# Artemis: How to stop consuming messages on error?

Tags: spring, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

How to configure ActiveMQ Artemis or my Spring JMS client to not consume any other message on error?

I've configured my broker as follows:

```
<addresses>
    <address name="SimplePointToPoint">
        <anycast>
            <queue name="SimplePointToPoint"/>
        </anycast>
    </address>
</addresses>
<address-settings>
    <address-setting match="SimplePointToPoint">
        <max-delivery-attempts>-1</max-delivery-attempts>
    </address-setting>
</address-settings>
```

This is the code of my consumer:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "SimplePointToPoint")
public void consumeMessage(Message<String> message) {
    if (message.getPayload().contains("error"))
        throw new RuntimeException();

    log.info("received message: {}", message.getPayload());
}
```

When sending `message1`, `message2 with error` and `message3` I want the consumer to process `message1` and retry `message2 with error` forever. `message3` should not be processed until `message2 with error` is successfully consumed. What actually happens is that `message3` gets consumed between retries. How to change this behavior? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ prefetch is 1000 by default.

See [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html).

> You can specify an instance of the ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy on an ActiveMQConnectionFactory or ActiveMQConnection. This allows you to configure all the individual prefetch values; as each different quality of service has a different value. e.g.
>
> persistent queues (default value: 1000)
>
> ...

Comment: Your answer applies to Apache ActiveMQ 5.x, but the question was about the Apache ActiveMQ Artemis broker.